# getProperties result in English

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

We have a Revit file originated in the Frech flavour of Revit.
Hence all the object properties are in French:
"Structural Columns" = "Poteaux porteurs"

Our custom script is looking for the English Categorie naming to filter through results.
Any chance to "getProperties" results in a uniform language, regardles of the originating Revit flavour?

Answer (score 0):

When you get object properties from the `viewer` with `viewer.getProperties(dbId,onSuccessCallback, onErrorCallback)` for example, you get an object with the key `displayName` which is in the language you used in your editor and `attributeName` which is in English and seems to be the reference property name, regardless of the language used.

Comment: Thx AlexAR, but its the "displayValue" i was hoping for. I want to filter "Revit Structural Columns" but in French the displayValue is "Revit Poteaux porteurs".

Comment: Maybe I should use CategoryId?

Comment: I think you can't get the translation of the `displayValue` as for families and types, this value can be modified in Revit if you use custom families.

Comment: Category naming in Revit is hard coded  / cannot be altered. Only in different language flavors of Revit (French, German, Chinese, ...) these namings are different

Comment: Yes, definitely use `CategoryId` if you have access to that. In the Revit API, the [`LabelUtils` `GetLabelFor(BuiltInCategory)` method](https://www.revitapidocs.com/2022/3c5057a7-b59e-c650-0d46-643f3bae218d.htm) provides a possibility to translate from `BuiltInCategory` and presumably the `CategoryId` to the language specific display string. You can even [switch the Revit UI language at startup a command line switch](https://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2020/03/coding-interior-elevations-and-command-line-options.html#3). This might not work in Design Automation though, since it has no UI.